# Examples of Datastore read/write from ajax?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

My single page app is hosted on Google's cloudstore. I love that I don't have to worry about a server. The app is, naturally, javascript heavy.

Now I would like to add a feature where users can store some data, generate a link to be shared with others and retrieve stored data. Think of a pastebin where some snippet of text is saved and a unique link is generated to be shared with others.

In fact, if it helps, think of this as my attempt to create a pastebin without having to setup a server.

It looks like Google's cloud datastore nosql solution is what I want. Given a key, it will return a snippet of text. However, all the examples on the documentation page imply that I have to setup a back end service using python, node, etc.

Questions:

1. Can't I just read and write from a web page, perhaps using ajax style http call (since I need to get and put text snippets once data has already been loaded)? I believe I can take care of cross-origin issues by changing some configs in the cloudstore static website server.
2. Obviously I don't want to serve any encryption keys from the web page. I'm hoping that since my site is served from Google as well, I can configure the nosql service handle permissions intelligently for this scenario.

Is there any documentation which shows how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Datastore is not supposed to be used from client side, it's a served side database. You cannot do that w/o having server side code to authenticate, authorize and validate db related requests.

But there're an alternative. Firebase is a ready to use backend for client side applications, including Javascript apps. It's a separate project, that belongs to Google but not (yet?) part of Google Cloud. Take a look - https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: I pretty sure I came across firebase before but never knew they were acquired by Google! Thanks, getting ready to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Although the API Rest is still beta, it is possible now to connect from a web client or anything RESTful capabilities. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/